# How to use Power Automate to set the expiry of Teams videos stored in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I want to automatically remove any expiration date associated with Teams videos stored in a Sharepoint folder using Power Automate. In order to do this I have:

1. Created a listener for new files created in a Sharepoint folder - using "When file is created (properties only)".
2. This is where I am stuck - I am unable to find an action that allows me to update the expiration date. I have found:

- Update file properties => however, when I select Site Address/Library Name, it only gives me the option to update "Image Tags", "Title", "Description", etc. but not the expiration.

I also looked at calling the Sharepoint API directly but wasn't able to find an example of an appropriate API call to make.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any SharePoint API or Action in Power Automate available to update the expiration date. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Comment: Thanks @Prasad-MSFT - do you have any thoughts on the response below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a POST request with the SetExpirationDate method. Below is an example of that approach.

URI

```
_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/YourSite/@{triggerOutputs()?['body/{FullPath}']}')/SetExpirationDate
```

Body Payload

```
{
"expirationDate":"2023-10-24T09:10:12.000Z"
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution @Expiscornovus I have implemented it but now get the following response:

`{ "d": {  "SetExpirationDate": null }}`

Does this indicate success?

Comment: Additionally can you share the documentation for this API call? I am unable to find it on google.

Comment: I found this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfilebyserverrelativeurl?view=sharepoint-csom

But it has no mention of SetExpirationDate.

Comment: I traced the request in the developer toolbar and tested it on a meeting recording file. After the flow run the date was adjusted. Btw, did you use the same headers?

Comment: Btw, I am not near a computer atm. But I can check what response I received in my test.

Comment: I did use those two headers yes.

Comment: Just to double check. What value did you use for your expirationDate property?

Comment: I also used Developer tools and did the same as you suggested above. I see that the response I pasted earlier is what is expected in a success situation. Thanks for your help.

P.S. I set the value to null.

Comment: I also double checked. It should be the correct response. I have added some additional screenshots to the answer to clarify.